# Calculating $\nabla_\mu T^{\mu\nu}$ in linear cosmological perturbation theory

Tags: homework-and-exercises, cosmology, perturbation-theory, stress-energy-momentum-tensor

I am trying to calculate $\nabla_\mu T^{\mu\nu}$ for perfect fluid in the context of the linear cosmological perturbation theory. I'm working in the Newtonian gauge. I have successfully calculated $\nabla_\mu T^{\mu}_0$ but in calculating $\nabla_\mu T^{\mu}_j$, I'm not getting the desired result discussed in the literature. I know that I will get downvoted if I directly ask here to show me how to get the correct result without showing how I tried to do it. On the other hand there are a lot of terms to type. So I will attach a photograph of my notebook in the following,
[image]

As you can see what I am getting is, $\nabla_\mu T^\mu_m=\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\left[(\bar{\rho}+\bar{P})v_m\right]+\partial_m\delta P+\Psi,_{m}(\bar{\rho}+\bar{P})+3H(\bar{\rho}+\bar{P})v_m$. In the literature the expression is almost similar but different that they have $4H(\bar{\rho}+\bar{P})v_m$. The full expression in the literature is,
$$\nabla_\mu T^\mu_m=\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\left[(\bar{\rho}+\bar{P})v_m\right]+\partial_m\delta P+\Psi,_{m}(\bar{\rho}+\bar{P})+4H(\bar{\rho}+\bar{P})v_m.$$
I am unable to resolve this discrepancy myself. So I would like to request someone to point out the mistake in my calculation or show how to get the desired result in the literature and that would be utmost helpful.

**Additional information for conventions used**
[image]

Comment: Can anyone verify the definitions I gave for four velocity of comoving observer are correct? I am talking about the $U^\mu=(1-\Psi,\frac{1}{a^2}v^i)$ and $U_\mu=(-(1+\Psi),v_i)$ ones. Please tell me given the metric tensor whether this is the correct choice? The error might be lurking in this definition because I am confident about all other steps.